# Laravel - How to set additional parameters in database connection string?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I'm currently migrating a legacy system to laravel and
I'm facing an issue regarding using additional parameters while connecting to the database.

Below is the current code:

```php
try {
    $dns = "pgsql:host=<HOST>;port=<NUMBER_PORT>;dbname=<DB_NAME>";
    $options = [PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true];
    $this->driver = new PDO($dns, <DB_USERNAME>, <DB_PASSWORD>, $options);
    
    $this->driver->query("SET app.current_tenant = {<TENANT_ID>}");
    $this->driver->query("SET app.current_institution = {<INSTITUTION_ID>}");

    $this->driver->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

My question is: how to set the ***app.current_tenant*** and ***app.current_institution*** parameters when connecting to the database in Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to implement your own database connection class, overriding the `connect()` method to do what you want. At a very basic level, this could look like this:

**app/Database/PostgresConnector.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Database;

use Illuminate\Database\Connectors\PostgresConnector as BaseConnector;

class PostgresConnector extends BaseConnector
{
    public function connect(array $config)
    {
        $pdo = parent::connect($config);
        $pdo->query("SET app.current_tenant = {<TENANT_ID>}");
        $pdo->query("SET app.current_institution = {<INSTITUTION_ID>}");

        return $pdo;
    }
}
```

Then you can write a service provider to use your custom connector instead of the default.
**app/Providers/DatabaseConnectorProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Database\PostgresConnector;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class DatabaseConnectorProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('db.connector.pgsql', PostgresConnector::class);
    }
}
```

Finally, ensure your service provider is being loaded in the providers array of `config/app.php`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. 
It perfectly solved my problem. 
A big hug.

Comment: I used this solution to override PDO object creation since I need the connection string to declare itself as a dblib connection even though Laravel itself gives error when declaring "dblib" as connection drive